# SQL Query syntax error in C++ program but works in MySQL Workbench

Tags: c++, mysql, exception, transactions, workbench

Here's the Query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
INSERT INTO n2 (idbin,vertices) VALUES("0",2),("1",2);
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
COMMIT;
```

The Exception:

```
MySQL ERR: SQLException in gen_simple_graphs.cc(printSqlException) on line 404
MySQL ERR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;INSERT INTO ' at line 1 (MySQL error code: 1064, SQLState: 42000 )
```

It works perfectly fine when I run that same query in MySQL workbench. In fact, I printed the query to console before the program executed it, copied it exactly and pasted it into workbench and it ran no problem.

This is what it looks like directly from the console:

```
START TRANSACTION;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;INSERT INTO n2 (idbin,vertices) VALUES("0",2),("1",2);SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;COMMIT;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not **a** query, it is eight queries/commands; depending on how you are connecting to the server, there could be a limit of one query/command per "Execute" method call. I believe the MySQL ODBC drivers have a setting for whether to allow it or not, and different APIs may have similar limitations.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks! On to the next noob mistake!

Answer (score 0):

The character `;` end a query then this  mean a new  statement  in MySQL WorkBench  IDE but inside  query in C++ the is  not allowed because so  became more query /statement .. and the you raise an  error .